# Linear map's amount between two vector spaces (abstract algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $V$ and $W$ be $\Bbb{F}_p$ vector spaces of dimensions $2$ and $3$ respectively. How many injective linear maps $V \rightarrow W$ are there? (Where $\Bbb{F}_p$ represents the finite field $\Bbb{Z}$ modulo $p$.)

So based on your hint, I think there should be p^3-1 w1 choice and then p^3-p w2 choice. The first restriction should be the without(0,0,0) and the second should be without a(v1) where a is 0 to p-1.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please try to avoid [no-clue-questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/how-to-prevent-no-clue-questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Denote $v_1$ and $v_2$ two basis vectors in $V$.

To define a linear map from $V$ to $W$, you first have to map $v_1$ onto a nonzero vector $w_1\in W$. In how may ways can you choose it?
Next you have to choose a vector $w_2$ to map $v_2$ onto. If you want the linear map to be injective, $w_2$ should not be collinear with $w_1$. How may choices do you have?

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer.  It is a series of hints.  If you get stuck, update your question, showing your work, then comment to this post asking for more detail in that step.

Can you count the number of points in $V$? in $W$?

Can you find a basis of $V$?  How many elements are in any basis of $V$?

By the linearity of linear maps, is a linear map completely specified once you specify where it sends each member of a basis?

How many ways are there to send a basis of $V$ to elements of $W$?